# How to make a new line in django messages.error

Tags: python, django, newline, django-messages

I have a line of my code

```
messages.error(request, ('ERROR: upload failed. Try again'))
```

popping up a message in my template

> upload failed. Try again

But I want to get a new line after the point, like:

> upload failed.
>   Try again

How do I get that?

I tryed

```
upload failed.\n Try again
```

and

```
upload failed.<br/> Try again
```

and

```
upload failed.{{text|linebreaks}} Try again
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You almost made it. You need to use [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).
In your case, this is what you will have:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

messages.error(request, mark_safe("ERROR: upload failed.<br/>Try again"))
```

Comment: To save y'all a click, don't forget to do `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`, so that this solution works (:

Comment: doesn't work <br/> gets escaped

Comment: @JSEvgeny It works. You need to use mark_safe.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect solution for your case, but you can call it two times:

```
messages.error(request, 'ERROR: upload failed.')
messages.error(request, 'Try again')
```

Instead of one message of two lines, you'll output two messages perfectly split.